# how do I save registers into sub indexed array?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

What I want to do is, after the user submits the subject that s/he wants, the code accesses the database and saves all the subjects that are related into the array. For now I want it to save all the data from the table 'class' into the array gradebook[]. I have tried a foreach loop but it is not working. I want to save all the register for the first row in gradebook[0], then the entire second register in gradebook[1] and so on. Also the `isset($_POST['subject'])` is not passing so it gives me this warning:

> Notice: Undefined variable: subject in C:\xampp\htdocs...

```
<?php
mysql_connect('localhost','root','root');
mysql_select_db('school');

if(isset($_POST['subject'])){
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM class WHERE subject=$subject");

    foreach ($result as $gradebook) {
      $gradebook[]=array('id'=>$id,'subject'=>$subject,'homework'=>$homework,'dueDate'=>$dueDate);
      echo "$gradebook <br>";
    }
/*  $table = '';
    $table .= '<table border="1">';
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($gradebook['subject']); $i++) {
        $table .= '<tr>';
        for ($j = 0; $j < count($gradebook['students']); $j++) {
            $table .= '<td width="50">&nbsp;</td>';
        }
        $table .= '</tr>';
    }
    $table .= '</table>';*/
}

?>
<form action="" method="post">
    <table border="0" width="200">
        <tr>
            <td width="80"><label>Subject</label></td>
            <td width="120"><input type="text" name="subject"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" align="right"><input type="submit" value="Create Table"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>    
</form>
<br />
<br />
```

this is my database

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.1.6
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Host: 127.0.0.1
-- Generation Time: Jul 25, 2014 at 05:52 AM
-- Server version: 5.6.16
-- PHP Version: 5.5.9

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;

--
-- Database: `school`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `class`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `class` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `subject` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
  `unit` varchar(5) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
  `homework` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
  `dueDate` date NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_spanish_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=11 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `class`
--

INSERT INTO `class` (`id`, `subject`, `unit`, `homework`, `dueDate`) VALUES
(1, 'Math', 'UI', 'Math work1', '2014-04-04'),
(2, 'Math', 'UI', 'Math work2', '2014-05-12'),
(3, 'Science', 'UI', 'Science work1', '2014-04-09'),
(4, 'Home Economics', 'UII', 'Home economics work1', '2014-04-16'),
(5, 'Math', 'UII', 'Math work 3', '2014-05-12'),
(6, 'Math', 'UIII', 'Math work4', '2014-05-21'),
(7, 'Science', 'UII', 'Science work2', '2014-05-14'),
(8, 'Physics', 'UI', 'Physics work1', '2014-05-06'),
(9, 'Math', 'UIII', 'Math work5', '2014-07-16'),
(10, 'Math', 'UIV', 'Math work6', '2014-07-14');

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
    <br />
    <br />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is probably due to undifined variable `$subject`, so in your query try this instead :

```
if(isset($_POST['subject'])){

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM class WHERE subject LIKE '%".$_POST['subject']."%'");
    if(!$result) {
    die("Database query failed: " . mysql_error());
}while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

      $gradebook[]=array('id'=>$row['id'],'subject'=>$row['subject'],'homework'=>$row['homework'],'dueDate'=>$row['dueDate']);


    }

$table = '';
    $table .= '<table border="1">';
     foreach ($gradebook as $row) 
    { 
       $table .=  '<tr>';
        $table .= '<td>' . $row['id'] . '</td>';
        $table .= '<td>' . $row['homework'] . '</td>';
        $table .= '<td>' . $row['dueDate'] . '</td>';
        $table .= '</tr>';
    }
    $table .= '</table>';
print($table);

}

?>
<form action="" method="post">
    <table border="0" width="200">
        <tr>
            <td width="80"><label>Subject</label></td>
            <td width="120"><input type="text" name="subject"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" align="right"><input type="submit" value="Create Table"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>    
</form>
<br />
<br />
```